# adobe flashplugin-installer keeps sending error message at startup (kde daemon on kubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, flash, kde, services

I have the adobe flashplugin installed (grmmmbl...) but kde daemon keep sending this error message at session startup :

[image: Error Message]

Saying it cannot find the flashplugin installer while i do not want it (and after attempt to purge by hand, i had the "not installed" message...

As i have this each time i log in, i would like to know how to disable this message (I couldn't find where it comes from searching the logs)

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same problem.

Everything is working well for you and all you want is only to remove this useless error message,isn't it?

The solution is here:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/user.d/data-downloads-failed-permanently
sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/user.d/data-downloads-failed
```

and you will get rid of it!

Simple et efficace!